# Is [suggestion] a worthwhile tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Currently [suggestion](/questions/tagged/suggestion) has 17 (formerly 33) questions in it, less than a dozen or so are really about "autocompletion" or similar ideas, whereas most of the others are questions asking for a suggestion.  But that seems a whole heck of a lot like a meta tag to me.  Should we just remove the tag from the ones where it's a meta tag and leave it for the ones about search/autocomplete?  Or should we blacklist this tag?

I'm seeking suggestions (ha!) from the community regarding whether or not we should keep the tag because perhaps it's a commonly-used term for the topics it's being used on, but to me in almost all cases there are better terms that aren't as generic sounding as "suggestion".  I just didn't want to impose my own colloquial vocabulary on others.

Comment: I went ahead and removed the instances where it was used as a meta tag.  I'm not sure it's a useful tag on the remaining questions, but I'll wait to see if anyone else wants to offer any opinions.

Comment: If anything it should be a synonym of [meta-tag:feature-request]

Comment: @ChrisF this is for SO, not MSO, though that's not a bad idea here ...

Comment: Ah - sorry, my misunderstanding

Comment: I don't think the word "suggestion" is the best, and like @Bill I have some skepticism about how useful a tag for suggestion functionality is, but auto-suggestions *are* a pretty frequent component so I'm thinking that we could do with keeping the tag in some state.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a feature where the system could suggest other (related) tags while not necessarily marking these tags synonyms.  So as a user starts typing [tag:suggestion], they could see other tags such as [tag:autocomplete].

Comment: @JeffMercado The best you can do at the moment is put the suggestions in the tag wiki excerpt. But that should be done very sparingly, because excerpts are supposed to be short and to the point. Mentioning other tag in the excerpt is for cases where there is a very high potential for confusion.

Comment: @Gilles: I wouldn't even consider that as an option. The excerpts and frankly, anything that should go in tag wikis should only be about the tag itself. It should not mention anything else unrelated. In this situation, it shouldn't even go there just because people misused the tag here on the site.  It's not something people who are familiar with the tag would mix up.